# USB stick "lights" under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb

Many USB sticks (thumb drives) have little lights that indicate they are active (for example many SanDisk thumb drives).

Under Windows XP, when you "Safely Remove USB Mass Storage Device" XP conveniently switches the lights off.

Under Windows 7,  the lights stay on.  I realize this is a "mere bagatelle" (but I DO find it surprisingly useful), but is it possible to restore that functionality?  Registry? Whatever?

Comment: Answer below.  Though you might find this interesting?  Or amusing?  Or not?  "USB Flash Pen Drive Won't Turn Off?"
http://www.pcqanda.com/dc/dcboard.php?az=show_topic&forum=2&topic_id=526173

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\usbhub\HubG` via regedit, Set `DisableOnSoftRemove (DWORD)` to 1.

The Microsoft Support KB 2401954 explains the behavior: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2401954

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, as long as you've safely removed that drive or have seen that prompt it should be fine. The light staying on may just be the drive itself. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-to-safely-remove-usb-drive-in-windows-7/661309ac-a390-4f8a-86b4-b78bb380976c